# How can I do a threshold effect with canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, filter, effect, threshold

I found this guide showcasing image filters/effects using canvas and JavaScript: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters

Though, I don’t have any idea on how to implement it. I’m not good with JavaScript (I’m a graphic designer), so I’m not even understanding the syntax. I extracted this code from the page, but I don’t know if it’s complete or how to use it:

```
Filters = {};

Filters.threshold = function(pixels, threshold) {
    var d = pixels.data;
    for (var i=0; i<d.length; i+=4) {
        var r = d[i];
        var g = d[i+1];
        var b = d[i+2];
        var v = (0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b >= threshold) ? 255 : 0;
        d[i] = d[i+1] = d[i+2] = v
    }
    return pixels;
};

threshold = function() {
  runFilter('threshold', Filters.threshold, 128);
}
```

[I want to replicate this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Md7Z.jpg) on a `div` (with CSS `background-image` properties), `img` or `canvas` element, it doesn’t matter as long as it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply this filter on an HTML `<div>`, then a canvas solution is not the best.

Instead look at [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) for the simple cases, or [SVG filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter) for the more complex ones.

The one you want is a simple one and can be achieved with CSS filters only:

```css
#target {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Md7Z.jpg);
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  filter: brightness(115%) grayscale(100%) contrast(5000%);
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: This is quite a clever solution. It just simplified the whole process without getting to JavaScript. I just implemented this and it works like a charm, even with other nested filters on the parent element.

Answer (score 2):

The filter works on image data [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData). Image data can not be displayed so needs to be converted to some displayable form, such as a canvas.

Also you need to get the image data from the image. Standard images do not give access to pixels so you will need to convert the image to a canvas to get the pixels.

**Note** that unsecured images (cross domain, local file store) may not give you pixel access. Some cross domain images will allow access if you provide the correct [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers in the request and the server accepts the request (as in example below).

### Example

I have added to the Filter object some helper functions that will copy, create and get pixels from a variety of image like sources.

`Filter` in the example abstracts the term image. In terms of the example an image is an image like object and can be any of `CSSImageValue`, `HTMLImageElement`,`SVGImageElement`, `HTMLVideoElement`, `HTMLCanvasElement`, `ImageBitmap`, `OffscreenCanvas` or `ImageData`.

```js
const image = new Image;
image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Late_model_Ford_Model_T.jpg";
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; // CORS 
image.addEventListener("load", () => applyFilter(image), {once: true});
const Filters = {
    createImage(w, h) {
        const can = document.createElement("canvas");
        can.width = w;
        can.height= h;  
        return can;
    },
    copyImage(img) {
        const image = this.createImage(img.width, img.height);
        const ctx = image.getContext("2d");
        if (img instanceof ImageData) { ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0) }
        else { ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height) }
        return image;
    },
    getPixels(img) {
        if (!(img instanceof HTMLCanvasElement)) { img = this.copyImage(img) }
        const ctx = img.getContext("2d");
        return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    },
    threshold(pixels, threshold, light = [255,255,255], dark = [0,0,0]) { // light, dark arrays of RGB
        var d = pixels.data, i = 0, l = d.length;
        while (l-- > 0) {
            const v = d[i] * 0.2126 + d[i+1] * 0.7152 + d[i+2] * 0.0722;
            [d[i], d[i+1], d[i+2]] = v >= threshold ? light : dark;
            i += 4;
        }
        return pixels;
    }

};
function applyFilter(image) {
    const pixels = Filters.getPixels(image);
    Filters.threshold(pixels, 100);
    const thresholdImage = Filters.copyImage(pixels);
    att.classList.remove("hide"); // Image can be seen so show attribution
    document.body.appendChild(image); // add original to page
    document.body.appendChild(thresholdImage); // add filtered to page 
}

/* Image source 
   By Rmhermen - Transferred from en.wikipedia to Commons., CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=468996 
*/
```

```css
.hide {display: none}
div { font-size: x-small }
canvas { width: 46% }
img { width: 46% }
```

```html
<div id="att" class="hide">By Rmhermen - Transferred from en.wikipedia to Commons., CC BY-SA 3.0, <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=468996">image source</a></div>
```

Comment: excellent threshold conversion, that was very helpful, thanks!